# Mysql Query to get last three records based on date without Limit

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have a legacy system which has a table like below where a book can have multiple reviews

book_reviews

| review_id | book_id | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 28163 | 2234 | 2021-01-12 07:58:14 |
| 28261 | 2212 | 2021-01-18 12:39:10 |
| 28153 | 2199 | 2021-01-12 08:03:53 |
| 28206 | 2194 | 2021-01-18 07:41:49 |
| 28250 | 2194 | 2021-01-18 07:33:23 |
| 28152 | 2194 | 2021-01-12 08:03:52 |
| 28118 | 2194 | 2021-01-11 07:14:34 |
| 28057 | 2194 | 2021-01-08 07:32:21 |
| 28061 | 2194 | 2021-01-08 07:30:54 |
| 28211 | 2193 | 2021-01-18 07:40:32 |

And I have to just extract 3 recent reviews for each book like following

| review_id | book_id | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 28163 | 2234 | 2021-01-12 07:58:14 |
| 28261 | 2212 | 2021-01-18 12:39:10 |
| 28153 | 2199 | 2021-01-12 08:03:53 |
| 28206 | 2194 | 2021-01-18 07:41:49 |
| 28250 | 2194 | 2021-01-18 07:33:23 |
| 28152 | 2194 | 2021-01-12 08:03:52 |
| 28211 | 2193 | 2021-01-18 07:40:32 |

I tried to use LIMIT but my version of MYSQL is prehistoric and does not allow Limit in subqueries.
Is there a better way with a join that I can achieve the same.

Comment: Your results have four reviews for one of the books.  That is confusing.

Comment: @GordonLinoff upvoting. Thanks for the pointing out the typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an old version of MySQL, I would suggest variables as the most efficient method:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             (@rn := if(@b = book_id, @rn + 1,
                        if(@b := book_id, 1, 1)
                       )
             ) as rn
      from (select t.* from t order by book_id, review_date desc
           ) t cross join
           (select @b := -1, @rn := 0) params
     ) t
where rn <= 3;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use analytical function as follows:

```
select t.* from
(select t.*,
       row_number() over (partition by book_id order by review_Date desc) as rn
  from your_Table t) t
where rn <= 3
```

If your Mysql version is lower than 8 then you can use the corelated query as follows:

```
select t.* 
  from your_table t
 where 3 >= (select count(*) from your_table tt
               where t.book_id = tt.book_id and tt.review_date <= t.review_Date)
```